# Best way to avoid memory leaks for Multiple Buttons in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, memory, uitableview, uibutton

I've got an array of buttons in a UITableViewCell.
I populated them all through the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but my tableview gets sluggish even though I have released everything.

Should I be using a custom UITableViewCell to populate?
Any suggestions on how to make this as smooth as possible for the user would be great.

Screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: post code. I bet $1 that you don't properly reuse your cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom cell / custom view pair for this specific cell, where you can draw all yours buttons in drawRect:. However, this would essentially draw all your buttons as an image so you wouldn't be able to tap them, but I guess you can always create a UITapGestureRecognizer to your cell (you'd still have to figure out which button was pressed by examining x,y values).

Still, I don't see any point in adding your tag buttons inside a UITableViewCell. You could come up for an alternate design in your UI, i.e. a UIView presented on top of the table, or a modal controller maybe.

Comment: Agreed, the UITableView Implmentation was not the best idea. Has now been changed to a subview added on top.